# как сжать динамический диск vmware

Tags: vmware

Работаю часто с виртуалками, например убунту сервер, провожу там всякие обработки данных. с утра машина весит 4гб, к вечеру уже 12гб 
Хотя в самой системе я все чищу удаляю, диск динамический задан, 30гб, но зараза постоянно растет)

машину выключаю, в меню настроек, есть работа с диском - сжать - пишет готово, но ничего не меняется...

должен же быть какая то утилита простая?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, сжимать диски просто так нельзя. ВМ занимает столько место, сколько реально занимает (обычно). Можно использовать snapshots и откатиться, потеряв данные, но освободив место. 
Но есть способы уменьшить размер диска (но только динамических):

1. можно уменьшить swap, можно использовать дефрагментацию для Windows систем.
2. Сжатие виртуального диска с помощью VMware Tools
3. также workstation имеет встроенные возможности clean up

Касательно второго пункта. Можно использовать VMware Tools, чтобы стереть пустые сектора диска в конце диска. Запустите VMware Toolbox (или vmware-toolbox для linux систем), перейдите в Shrink вкладку, выберите диск, Prepare to Shrink и следуйте инстукциям.

подробнее [тут](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2019649)

Comment: я так и не понял как в винде запустить эту vmware tools, где конкретно этот exe лежит и как он называется??

Comment: и можно подробнее что за возможности clean up

Comment: двойной клик на иконку vm tools в трее или же  Start > Control Panel > VMware Tools. workstation, значит, правой кнопкой на машину - > manage -> clean up disks

Answer (score 1):

В интернете описано много способов, но мне помогла только утилита [VMware vCenter Converter Standalone](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/info/slug/infrastructure_operations_management/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/6_2_0)
Нажимаете в ней Convert machine и следуя мастеру выбираете исходную систему, целевую остлаьные параметры оставляете по дефолту. У меня диск с 60Гб на выходе получилось 19 Гб.

---

**P.S. Перед любыми манипуляциями делайте бекап виртуальной машины.**